# SMTP error could not Authenticated using SMTP in .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, outlook, smtp

Credentials were Correct.
5.7.57 SMTP - Client was not authenticated to send mail, 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful

returning this error while sending email using SMTP in .Net

This Application is deployed in Azure
Not sure what is causing the issue, previoulsy it was working suddenly it stopped.

Tried with Exchange Server throwing 401 unAuthorized error.

Answer (score 1):

That's because .NET SMTP class is old and doesn't support authentication.

Take a look at its cross platform replacement. Microsoft recommends this library.

https://dotnetfoundation.org/projects/mailkit